# waitpid() error problem

Tags: fork, wait

I wrote code to print *pid* in order `parent->g3->c2->g1->g2->c1`.

So I used `wait()`, and `waitpid()`. But I failed.

So I wrote "finish"code to know what is problem.

And I knew that c1 ignore the waitpid and print what->finish.

How can I solve this problem

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
pid_t c1,c2,g1,g2,g3;

printf("parent:%d\n", (int)getpid());
c1=fork();
int status;
if (c1>0) {
        c2=fork();
        if (c2==0) {
            g3=fork();
            if (g3==0) {
                    printf("g3:%d\n",(int)getpid());
            } else if (g3>0) {
            wait(&status);
            printf("c2:%d\n",(int)getpid());
            }
       }
} else if (c1==0) {
        waitpid(c2,&status,WUNTRACED);
    printf("what\n");
    g1=fork();
    if (g1>0) {
            g2=fork();
            if (g2==0) {
                printf("g2:%d\n",(int)getpid());
            } else if (g2>0) {
                    waitpid(g1,&status,WUNTRACED);
                    printf("c1:%d\n", (int)getpid());
            }
        } else if (g1==0) {
            waitpid(g2,&status,WUNTRACED);
            printf("g1:%d\n",(int)getpid());
            } else {
                printf("failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
} else {
    printf("main failed\n");
    exit(1);
} printf("finish\n");
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> pid_t c1,c2,g1,g2,g3;
>
> printf("parent:%d\n", (int)getpid());
> c1=fork();
> int status;
> if (c1>0) {
>      ....
> } else if (c1==0) {
>         waitpid(c2,&status,WUNTRACED);
> ```

the `c2` variable was never set, so it may contain whatever garbage it happened to be on the stack. The compiler would warn you about it if you run it with the `-Wall` flag.

Also, you should **always** check the return value of `waitpid`; that would've also caught the bug.

And after a `fork`, do not assume that the child will be scheduled to run before the parent or vice-versa.

> ```
>     printf("what\n");
>     g1=fork();
>     if (g1>0) {
>             ...
>         } else if (g1==0) {
>             waitpid(g2,&status,WUNTRACED);
> ```

Same thing as above, the `g2` variable is used without being initialized.

Also, the return value of `main` should be `int`, not `void`.

And you should always compile with the `-O2 -Wextra -Wall` flags on, that will save you a lot of trouble. If you find some warnings superfluous, you can turn them off individually; eg. (`-Wno-parentheses`, `-Wno-unused`).

Answer (score 1):

I verified this code with `gcc 6.3.0` and it is working properly there.
Well this code prints them in the order in which you asked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static int *glob_var;

int main()
{
int c1,c2,g1,g2,g3;
glob_var = mmap(NULL, sizeof *glob_var, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
printf("parent:%d\n", (int)getpid());
*glob_var = 0;
c1=fork();
int status;
if (c1>0) {
        c2=fork();
        if (c2==0) {
            g3=fork();
            if (g3==0) {
                printf("g3:%d\n",(int)getpid());
            } else if (g3>0) {
            wait(&status);
            printf("c2:%d\n",(int)getpid());
            *glob_var = 1;
            }
   }
} else if (c1==0) {
       while(*glob_var == 0);

    printf("what\n");
    g1=fork();
    if (g1>0) {
        waitpid(g1,&status,WUNTRACED);
        g2=fork();

        if (g2==0) {

            printf("g2:%d\n",(int)getpid());
        } else if (g2>0) {
                waitpid(g2,&status,WUNTRACED);
                printf("c1:%d\n", (int)getpid());
        }
    } else if (g1==0) {

        printf("g1:%d\n",(int)getpid());
        } else {
            printf("failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
} else {
    printf("main failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

}
```

I made few chagnes.

I just added `waitpid(g2,&status,WUNTRACED);` in the starting of

```
 else if (g2>0) {
            waitpid(g2,&status,WUNTRACED);
            printf("c1:%d\n", (int)getpid());
    }
```

conditional statement so g2 will be finished before c1.

And `waitpid(g1,&status,WUNTRACED);` added in the conditional statement `if(g1>0)` so g1 will be finished before g2.

And also I used a `glob_var` which is a global variable declared as `static int *glob_var;` and used `mmap` to share it between parent and child.

```
 glob_var = mmap(NULL, sizeof *glob_var, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
            MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

And used it as a semaphore to execute `c2` before `c1` and it is working like when c2 will be finished it will then change the value of semaphore from *0 to 1* and after that only`while(*glob_var == 0)` loop will break `else if(c1==0)` condition will continue.

And also there is no need of `waitpid(c2,&status,WUNTRACED);` in `else if (c1==0)` so I removed it.